# Compiler warning "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './locale'" since I use momentjs in my react app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, webpack, momentjs

I get the following warning since I use moment.js in my application (npm 5.4.2, react 15.4, typescript 2.5.3, webpack 2.2.1, webpack-dev-server 2.4.1).

In ./src/utils/commons.ts I use momentjs and it's working fine, but I get the  warning.

Any help appreciated.

```
WARNING in ./~/moment/src/lib/locale/locales.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './locale' in 'C:\myproject\node_modules\moment\src\lib\locale'
 @ ./~/moment/src/lib/locale/locales.js 65:16-60
 @ ./~/moment/src/lib/locale/locale.js
 @ ./~/moment/src/moment.js
 @ ./src/utils/commons.ts
 @ ./src/components/Login.tsx
 @ ./src/app.tsx
 @ ./src/index.tsx
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 webpack/hot/dev-server react-hot-loader/patch webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 webpack/hot/only-dev-server ./src/index.tsx
webpack: Compiled with warnings.
```

Comment: Mentioned bug can hit not only react apps or create-react-app but all users of the moment v2.19

Comment: @AndyTheos I can't see substantial diffence between the accepted answer here and the accepted in the question linked as possible duplicate. Even the Github issue is the same ([#4216](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/4216)). That is why I marked as _Possible duplicate_

Comment: @VincenzoC agreed, i was pointing to the fact that we can edit this duplicates to mention all bugs regarding this issue, not only react\cra

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a bug in Moment v2.19, due to changes in require:
[Issue on Github](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/4216)

You can lock out 2.18.1 version in your package.json or apply fixes, mentioned in the link.

Comment: Works perfect, thank you. :o)